# iphone Crash log: preventSuspend preventIdleSleep

Tags: iphone, audio, crash, streaming

I have written an iPhone app that streams several radio stations.  The app works fine and doesn't seem to crash and it even runs in the background fine.  the only problem is that when I look at the crash logs on my iPhone, there is always multiple instances of the above crash log.  This doesn't seem normal.  Is there anything that I can do to get rid of this crash?  Again, the user never sees a crash and the app actually continues to run beyond 600 second in the background just fine.

```
Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x8badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
CBCJazz[1196] has active assertions beyond permitted time: 
{(
  <SBProcessAssertion: 0x63f8f90> identifier: UIKitBackgroundCompletionTask process: CBCJazz[1196] permittedBackgroundDuration: 600.000000 reason: finishTask owner pid:1196 preventSuspend  preventIdleSleep 
)}
```

Thanks for your help,

-RawMean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most probably you don't end correctly your background tasks. The problem is each time
the app goes in background the new task is created. And every task must be ended. See 
[UIKitBackgroundCompletionTask - iPhone application crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726254/uikitbackgroundcompletiontask-iphone-application-crash/4783926#4783926)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the key `UIBackgroundModes` to your `Info.plist` file. This key should indicate an array, and you should add one string element whose value is `audio`.

Do not just start a background task and ignore the termination warning from the watchdog. If you already completed this step, then the crash logs may be there from before you did that.

For more information, see [Declaring the Background Tasks You Support](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW8) in the [iOS Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  My Info.plist does include UIBackgroundModes as suggested above (I don't think the audio would have continued to play in the background otherwise, anyway).  Also, the crash logs are definitely not from before; I keep deleting them and they keep being generated.

Comment: Without indicated key the app will not play audio in the background, but not crash trying.

Comment: @AlexeyVMP You're absolutely wrong. He was starting a background task and suspending idle timeout to stream the music instead of using the correct key and never ending the task. That crash is because the watchdog is terminating the app after it doesn't respond to timeout warnings.